# Based on the result, how to remove data that is above the top point of the boxplot?

Tags: pandas, numpy, bigdata, data-science

I have data that I am analyzing based on `IQR`, based on the result I would like to delete data that is above the top point of the `boxplot`

What I managed to find is the code

```
df.loc[(data['Test1'] < 52)]
```

In place of the number 52, I would like there to be a variable
For example `upper` which matters

I am looking for something that will be better than `df.drop` or `df.loc`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create data frame
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\\Pulpit\Live\A8EEC900.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Test1'])
q1 = np.round(df.quantile(0.25), 2)
q3 = np.round(df.quantile(0.75), 2)
iqr = np.round(q3 - q1, 2)
upper = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
lower = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
min_value = np.round(df.min(), 2)
dt = df.loc[(data['Test1'] < 52)]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the data to be able to reproduce your code?

Comment: I don't totally understand the question either. BTW, you can just replace 52 with upper in your code snippet as it's written.

Comment: Can't you just use the `upper` variable instead of 52?

Comment: @AdityaValue Error : Can Compare identically-labeled series objects